# current time tooltip when i hover on a slider html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

Hello friends i was working on making a html5 video player and i got stuck with the problem. I want that whenever we hover on the seekbar a small box should appear and display the time at the point on the seekbar. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a trigger on hovering the `seekbar` somewhere. I don't see the code of your function `updatebar()` but it should be the answer on how to compute the corresponding time of the video.

Comment: Hey the `updatebar()` is actually a variable which is having a function

Comment: Thanks bro your hint actually worked i just thinked a little bit and i was successful in making the tooltip this is just all because of you thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Guys:

At last i have got a way to make the current Time tooltip in a more responsive way than ever here is a simple Example:

```js
var video = $('video')[0];
var timeDrag = false;
  $('.seek-con').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    timeDrag = true;
  updatebar(e.pageX);
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(timeDrag) {
   timeDrag = false;
   updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(timeDrag) {
   updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 var updatebar = function(x) {
  var progress = $('.seek-con');
  
  //calculate drag position
  //and update video currenttime
  //as well as progress bar
  var maxduration = video.duration;
  var position = x - progress.offset().left;
  var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
  if(percentage > 100) {
   percentage = 100;
  }
  if(percentage < 0) {
   percentage = 0;
  }
  $('.seek-inner').css('width',percentage+'%');
  video.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
 };
  $('.seek-con').mousemove(function(e){
       var progress = $('.seek-con');
  //calculate drag position
  //and update video currenttime
  //as well as progress bar
  var maxduration = video.duration;
  var position = e.pageX - progress.offset().left;
  var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
  if(percentage > 100) {
   percentage = 100;
  }
  if(percentage < 0) {
   percentage = 0;
  }
    var x = percentage / 100 * video.duration;
   $('.tooltip-con')[0].innerHTML = timeFormat(x);
   var offestY = progress.offset().top;
    var y = e.clientX - 33;
    $('.tooltip-con')[0].style.top = progress[0].offsetTop-62 + "px";
$('.tooltip-con').css('margin-left',y+'px');
  });
  $('.seek-con').hover(function(){
    $('.tooltip-con').fadeIn();
  },function(){
    $('.tooltip-con').fadeOut();
  });
var timeFormat = function(seconds){
  var m = Math.floor(seconds/60)<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds/60) : Math.floor(seconds/60);
  var s = Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)) : Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
  return m+":"+s;
 };
   $('video').on('timeupdate',function(){
       var width = 100 / video.duration * video.currentTime;
        $('.seek-inner').css('width',width+'%');
   });
```

```css
.seek-con{
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#222;
}
.seek-inner{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:cyan;
}
.tooltip-con{
   background-color:#555;
   padding:10px;
   width:40px;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="https://givemesomething.000webhostapp.com/video.mp4" height="100%" width="100%" controls></video>
<!--- The Seek bar --->
<div class="tooltip-con">00:00</div>
<div class="seek-con">
   <div class="seek-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the logic !